# Show hidden toolbar after fragment change

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I have following question:

main_activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    .......>


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ......>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            ....../>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        ....../>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When FrameLayout contains a fragment with a recyclerview, swiping the recyclerview up does scroll up the toolbar.

Following scenario is the problem:

- user scrolls up the toolbar by scrolling recyclerview
- user swipes from left and opens drawer
- user then navigates to another page
- another fragment is shown on screen BUT TOOLBAR IS STILL HIDDEN

This code peforms the fragment change:

```
fragment = .. get new fragment ..
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Adding this code doesn't help:

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

I also tried:

```
toolbar.translationY(0).start();
```

but with no success.

How can I make a scrolled-up (not visible) toolbar programmatically make scroll down again?

Comment: Never mind. appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true); did the trick.

Comment: Hmm having the same issue. .setExpanded() does expand the toolbar, but all the content in that fragment is pushed down. Did you encounter anything similar?

Comment: yes, I encountered it, but unfortunately I had to disable the scrolling toolbar temporarily (it clashed with the scrollbar I'm using) and postponed solving this problem. One thing though, I try to use only one Activity throughout the whole app and use Fragments only. Some fragments have scrolling content and others don't. Maybe using multiple Activities could solve the problem ?

Comment: I'm using a similar architecture (Fragments mostly). I ended up just putting a margin below the content that was being push down to force it back up. It looks alright but I'm still interested in a proper solution. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You should provide appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true) as an answer if it helped you. ;)

Answer (score 6):

I ended up calling

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true)
```

during every fragment creation inside the

```
onCreateView
```

method of an abstract class every fragment is inheriting from :

```
public abstract class AbstractFragmentBase extends Fragment {
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // other code
        customAppBar.setExpanded(true, true);
        // other code
    }
}
```